# Using Qt Project on Another Computer "invalid use of incomplete type ui::ProjectName" error

Tags: qt

I followed the steps, to continue programming and debugging a qt project on a computer other than the original, found in another Qt Question page.

1. Move qt project folder to usb
2. delete ProjectName.Pro.User file from folder
3. open qt project on other computer and reconfigure when prompted.

However When I try to build my project now it gives me this error "invalid use of incomplete type ui::ProjectName" whenever there is a line like `ui->widgetobject.setText();` or `ui->setupUI(this);` Any ideas how to fix this? the code has not changed at all

original computer is a windows 7, other is a windows 10 partition

Comment: You could tell us the characteristics of both devices, ie OS, compiler and Qt version.

Comment: Try running make clean and then run qmake in the build menu of Qt Creator.

Comment: You just saved my work project @eyllanesc